# Execute procedure in a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, execute

Is it possible to execute a stored procedure inside a trigger?

Thank you

Comment: if i were to just execute it myself, then it'll work. i want to create a trigger where it will execute it when there is value in a field

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, like this:

```
create or replace trigger trg
after insert on emp
for each row
begin
   myproc(:new.empno, :new.ename);
end;
```

Comment: what is :new.empno? [means :new?]

Comment: @Freelancer: in Oracle row-level triggers you can refer to column values before and after the triggering statement's effect using :old and :new.  This was meant to be a row-level trigger, I have just added the missing `for each row` part.

Comment: I'm surprised that after nearly 4 years no one has pointed out the error in my original answer (the missing `for each row`)!

Comment: @PieterDeBie, no execute statement indeed.  `execute immediate` would be used to run a procedure dynamically. i.e. if you didn't know the name of the procedure you would be running until the trigger fired - which is not typical.

Comment: what is meant by   myproc(:new.empno, :new.ename);

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can fire a procedure from a Trigger.
But, keep in mind that trigger & procedur
e should not acess the same table.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server it is.  What DBMS are you using?

ETA: Oracle, eh?  I've no personal experience with it, but [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E10405_01/doc/appdev.120/e10380/triggers_proc_mysql.htm) seems to indicate that you can.  I found it by googling "oracle trigger stored procedure".

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Just keep in mind that a trigger can fire for every row affected with a DML trigger. So your stored procedure should be optimized or you could will run into performance issues.  Triggers are a good thing but you just have to keep in mind the performance issues that can come up when using them.