# Two triggers, one procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Can't solve problem with sending only one mail instead of two.

I have got two tables with report status and information about logs. 
In first table I put in trigger condition like that:

```
create or replace TRIGGER test1
conditions
begin
send email
end.
```

On second table I create a similar trigger `test2`.

My objective is not to send 2 emails but only 1 only even when the conditions from either the `test1` trigger and the `test2` trigger are both existing in the database.

So I look on something like this: [Execute procedure in a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709399/execute-procedure-in-a-trigger)

But don't know how to make procedure two check if two triggers ran.

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you share your code so that it gets easier to help you.

Comment: Not sure how your email is sent, but if it is calling some other STMP or external process, then doing that directly from a trigger can be problematic.  What if the DML is rolled-back?  If the email sending process is not part of a transaction, then you cannot "undo" that.  You could create a work request table and have the triggers write to that, then have a process or Oracle AQ read that table and send the emails.

Comment: Will your 2 tables be updated in the same transaction? If not the 1st one cannot know it should not send the email at once. What is the condition you check in your trigger?

Comment: Succinctly, I'm tolerably sure that what you want can't be achieved reliably and sanely.  Triggers in different tables are fired at different times.  Unless the body of the second trigger also checks the condition for the first and only sends email if its own condition is satisfied while the other is not, … but ouch, my brain hurts.  Neither condition is going to fire very often, is it (as in not more than a few times per day, and preferably almost zero times per week), so dual mails aren't going to hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have acces to creating an extra table. Assume TRIGGER test1 runs only on (condition=)monday ... and TRIGGER test2 runs only on (condition=)tuesday. When test1 runs it does not send an email right away but it inserts a record in the extra table for - *example* - customer_A. When test2 runs it checks whether customer_A already got mail. If so then no new mail will be send. If not ... then a new mail will be send. This way customer_A never gets a mail on monday *and* on tuesday. Customer_A is an unique identifier in the table. After a certain period the table should be cleaned up or you introduce a time mechanism that keeps track of the most recent mails send.

Comment: That would be a solution but dont have access to create tables or modify data inisde.

Comment: That is a pity. It would be nice you could build your application custom made. An escape option could be:  your write your recipients from inside the 1th trigger - via UTL_FILE - to a file. The 2th trigger checks the file and acts according like it. This way the file acts as a table outside the database. But all together its not a very elegant solution.